# bash getopts with multiple and mandatory options

Tags: bash, getopts

Is it possible to use getopts to process multiple options together? For example, myscript -iR or myscript -irv.

Also, I have a situation where based on a condition script would need mandatory option. For example, if argument to script is a directory, I will need to specify -R or -r option along with any other options (myscript -iR mydir or myscript -ir mydir or myscript -i -r mydir or myscript -i -R mydir), in case of file only -i is sufficient (myscript -i myfile).

I tried to search but didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can concatenate the options you provide and `getopts` will separate them. In your `case` statement you will handle each option individually.

You can set a flag when options are seen and check to make sure mandatory "options" (!) are present after the `getopts` loop has completed.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
rflag=false
small_r=false
big_r=false
    
usage () { echo "How to use"; }
    
options=':ij:rRvhm'
while getopts $options option
do
    case "$option" in
        i  ) i_func;;
        j  ) j_arg=$OPTARG;;
        r  ) rflag=true; small_r=true;;
        R  ) rflag=true; big_r=true;;
        v  ) v_func; other_func;;
        h  ) usage; exit;;
        \? ) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
        :  ) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
        *  ) echo "Unimplemented option: -$option" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done

if ((OPTIND == 1))
then
    echo "No options specified"
fi

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if (($# == 0))
then
    echo "No positional arguments specified"
fi
    
if ! $rflag && [[ -d $1 ]]
then
    echo "-r or -R must be included when a directory is specified" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This represents a complete reference implementation of a `getopts` function, but is only a sketch of a larger script.

Comment: Many thanks Dennis. I have used the flags as you suggested. I tried to simplify the logic by concatenating options and storing them in a variable and later doing processing based on the options provided.

Comment: The difference between unimplemented and unknown option is that for the former an option was supplied which matches an option character in `$options`, but no entry in the `case` statement and for the latter an option was supplied which doesn't match any character in `$options`.

Comment: Note that you do not have to prefix variable names with `$` within arithmetic blocks; so you can just do `shift $((OPTIND-1))`

Comment: By the way `*  ) echo "Unimplemented option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;` should state `-$option` and not `-$OPTARG` otherwise it says the _argument_ to the option is unimplemented rather than the _flag_ is unimplemented.

The original way using `-$OPTARG`:
`
./foo.bash -m foo
Unimplemented option: -foo
`

If you use `-$option` you get what's expected:
`
./foo -m foo
Unimplemented option: -m
`

Comment: @ElvenSpellmaker: Did you test it? Did you read the documentation? "If the first character of optstring is a  colon,  silent  error reporting is used." and "If getopts is silent, then a colon (:) is placed in name and _OPTARG is set to the option character found_." [emphasis mine]

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Taking your exact code produces exactly what I said on bash.

Just add `m` to the list of options and then run the script specifying the `-m` flag.

`$ bash /tmp/foo.bash -m foo`
`Unimplemented option: -`

Comment: @ElvenSpellmaker: I apologize. You are correct. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Nice one, thanks for editing.