# How to print usage and missing argument error in bash?

Tags: bash

I have got a bash script which needs 5 arguments. I want to print usage and missing argument error if any of them are missing and exit there. Also help option which just print $usage.

```
#script.sh
usage="$0 param1 param2 param3 param4 param5
         param1 is ..
         param2 is ..
         param3 is ..
         param4 is ..
         param5 is .."

#if script.sh
# prints $usage and all param missing

#if script.sh param1 param2 param3
# print $usage and param4 and param5 missing and exit and so on

# script.sh -h
# just print $usage
```

Comment: Consider using `getopts`, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11279500/5128464).

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
var=${1:?error message}
```

which stores in `$var` the value of `$1` if it is set, and if not, displays the `error message` and stop the execution.

For example:

```
src_dir="${1:?Missing source dir}"
dst_dir="${2:?Missing destination dir}"
src_file="${3:?Missing source file}"
dst_file="${4:?Missing destination file}"

# if execution reach this, nothing is missing

src_path="$src_dir/$src_file"
dst_path="$dst_dir/$dst_file"
echo "Moving $src_path to $dst_path"
mv "$src_path" "$dst_path"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
usage() {
    echo the usage message
    exit $1
}

fatal() {
    echo error: $*
    usage 1
}

[ "$1" = -h ] && usage 0

[ $# -lt 1 ] && fatal param1..param5 are missing
[ $# -lt 2 ] && fatal param2..param5 are missing
[ $# -lt 3 ] && fatal param3..param5 are missing
[ $# -lt 4 ] && fatal param4 and param5 are missing
[ $# -lt 5 ] && fatal param5 is missing

# all good. the real business can begin here
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it.

```
if [ $# -ne 5 ]
then
    echo "$0 param1 param2 param3 param4 param5
          You entered $# parameters"
    PC=1
    for param in "$@"
    do
       echo "param${PC} is $param"
       PC=$[$PC +1]
    done
fi
```