# Parse combination of command-line arguments and flags in bash

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write bash script which will read multiple filenames and a target directory, which is optional.

`./myfile -t /home/users/ file1 file2`

I have tried the following code, but I am not able to handle different scenarios mentioned below:

```
while getopts "t:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    t)
      echo "-t was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG"
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

But the code should handle different scenarios like:
`./myfile file1 file2 -t /home/users/`, 
`./myfile file1  -t /home/users/ file2 file3`, 
`./myfile file1 file2 file3 file4`
and should be able to read the files.

Comment: "Traditional" unix command syntax requires that options come before positional parameters, and this is what `getopts` supports. If you want to allow options later in the sequence, you need to do the parsing yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `while` loop to `read` and `shift` the arguments might be easier in this case.
In the example below the arguments are looped through to look for the string `-t` in which case the arguments array is shifted one step and the now nr 1 index is supposed to be the optional homedir. In all the other cases the item is moved to another array called `files`.

```
#! /bin/bash

files=()
homedir=
while (( $# > 0 )); do
    case "$1" in
        -t )
            shift
            homedir="$1"
            ;;
        * )
            files+=("$1")
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
echo "${files[@]}"
echo "$homedir"
```

Answer (score 0):

After your `while` loop, you need to `shift` out any options and their arguments. This works even if there aren't any flags/flag arguements.

```
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

Then the rest of the arguments are available in `"$@"` and can be dealt with in any of the usual ways. For example:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    something_with "$arg"
done
```

For some more information, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279500/26428).