# Getopts default case bash script

Tags: linux, bash, switch-statement, getopts

I want to use getopts but the default case doesn't work.

The code that I tried is:

```sh
while getopts "sdp" arg; do
case "$arg" in
s) 
    echo "1" 
;;
p)
    echo "2" 
;;
d) 
   echo "3" 
;;
*) 
   echo "default"
;;
esac
```

when I run the process: ./myTask

I didn't receive any output

Comment: so what is the question. what do you want?

Comment: the default case doesn't work.

Comment: `getopts` returned zero status and the `while` loop never executed, thus the "default case" never executed.

Comment: That's the default of the `case` statement, but it means something specific in the context of `getopts`: That you have an option defined but no clause to handle it. Please see a reference implementation of a `getopts` function in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279500/26428).

Answer (score 2):

It's working as intended.

The default case is not to handle the case where you don't have arguments, but the case where you supply invalid arguments:

```
$ ./myTest -X
./myTest: illegal option -- X
default
```

Normally you would write a usage message in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default of the `case` statement, but it means something specific in the context of `getopts`: That you have an option defined but no clause to handle it.

If you run `./myTask -z`, for example, you will see the output of "default" as @that_other_guy states in another answer here.

If you want to output something that indicates that no option was supplied:

Then after the `while getopts` block but before the `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` line, do this (with whatever processing you want inside the `if` block:

```
if ((OPTIND == 1))
then
    echo "No options specified"
fi
```

Note that this does not indicate that no *arguments* were specified (e.g. `./myTask` as in your question). To do something with that, add this *after* the `shift` line:

```
if (($# == 0))
then
    echo "No positional arguments specified"
fi
```

Please see a reference implementation of a `getopts` function in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279500/26428).