# How to pass multiple flag and multiple arguments in getopts in shell script?

Tags: bash, getopts

Answer given here doesn't here any of my questions: [bash getopts with multiple and mandatory options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279423/bash-getopts-with-multiple-and-mandatory-options)

I am new to shell script and trying to write a shell script with `getopts` meanwhile I couldn't find answers to the below questions. Can somebody please help here?

This is the script I've started writing:

> ```
>  #!/bin/bash
>   while getopts c:t:x: option ; do
>   case $option in
>     c)
>       java -jar $file --fail-if-no-tests --include-classname "$OPTARG" --scan-class-path $file --include-tag regression
>       ;;
>     t)
>       java -jar $file --fail-if-no-tests --include-classname '.*' --scan-class-path $file --include-tag "$OPTARG"
>       ;;
>     c | t)
>       java -jar $file --fail-if-no-tests --include-classname "$OPTARG" --scan-class-path $file --include-tag "$OPTARG"
>       ;;
>     *)
>       usage
>   esac
>   done
> ```

1. How do I pass multiple flags? `For example runner.sh -c classname -t tagname` I Tried using `ct`, `c|t` in the `getopts` but did not work.
2. How do I pass multiple arguments for one flag? `For example runner.sh -g arg1 arg2`
3. Is there a way if I don't provide any flag
   it will run by default statement. I tried to achieve this using `*`
   but there is one issue with this approach. In case the wrong flag is
   provided it will always run default statement.

Comment: 1.  Every flag (i.e. -c and -t) has its own argument (i.e. classname and tagname), so why do you want to use `ct` or `c|t`? You can use `ct` when flags do not take arguments I guess.  2. You can try putting arguments in quotes like `runner.sh -g "arg1 arg2"`.

Comment: @nino 1.  I need to provide an option where user can pass argument for both (-c and -t) at the same time like `runner.sh -c classname -t tagname` the script i have above only picks up `-c` because it comes first. 2. I tried using double quotes but did not work.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I'll put the answer nelow.

Comment: @nino Looks like this should work for me. Can you also advise how do I check two variables are empty or not? I am trying to use [ -z "$CLASSNAME"  && -z "$TAGNAME"] but not working.

Comment: I think you can use double brackets `[[ -z "$CLASSNAME" && -z "$TAGNAME"]]` or `[ -z "$CLASSNAME" ] && [ -z "$TAGNAME"]`

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```sh
while getopts 'c:t:x:' option; do
    case "$option" in
        c ) classname="$OPTARG" ;;
        t ) tagname="$OPTARG" ;;
        x ) xvar="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done

## now you can use the variables in your command
```